# What is the best way to read from Linux /proc interfaces using C user space code?

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel

According to `man 5 proc`, one can use the `/proc` filesystem to access the following information on Linux:

```
   /proc/[pid]/maps
          A file containing the currently mapped memory regions and their access
          permissions.

          The format is:

          address           perms offset  dev   inode   pathname
          08048000-08056000 r-xp 00000000 03:0c 64593   /usr/sbin/gpm
          08056000-08058000 rw-p 0000d000 03:0c 64593   /usr/sbin/gpm
          08058000-0805b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
          40000000-40013000 r-xp 00000000 03:0c 4165    /lib/ld-2.2.4.so
          40013000-40015000 rw-p 00012000 03:0c 4165    /lib/ld-2.2.4.so
          4001f000-40135000 r-xp 00000000 03:0c 45494   /lib/libc-2.2.4.so
          40135000-4013e000 rw-p 00115000 03:0c 45494   /lib/libc-2.2.4.so
          4013e000-40142000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
          bffff000-c0000000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0

          where "address" is the address space in the process that it occupies,
          "perms" is a set of permissions:

               r = read
               w = write
               x = execute
               s = shared
               p = private (copy on write)

          "offset" is the offset into the file/whatever, "dev" is the device
          (major:minor), and "inode" is the inode on that device.  0 indicates
          that no inode is associated with the memory region, as the case would
          be with BSS (uninitialized data).

          Under Linux 2.0 there is no field giving pathname.
```

I don't really want to be writing text parsing code in C; I'd rather just make calls to the OS and read the information directly into structures. I looked in `/usr/include/linux` to see if there was an obvious structure with APIs, but didn't see anything.

So, two part question:

1. Can this be considered a "bad idea"? That is, should user programs just bite the bullet and read text from `/proc` in case the kernel interfaces change? If so, is there an accepted "best practice" for reading from `/proc` using C? (`fscanf()`? Regular expressions?)
2. How would I go about finding the documentation for the kernel interfaces (assuming they exist) which would allow me to directly read this data? (Is the kernel source itself the best place to start? If so, where in the kernel source should I look?) Bonus points if you know what interface can provide the `/proc/[pid]/maps` data specifically. =)

Comment: Busybox "top" at least reads /proc files and screen-scrapes them. I think there's various info that's not available any other way from userland. It is ugly, though.

Comment: seems straight forward just with `strtok` and `atoi`. `'\n'` is a record separator, `' '` is a field separator, and then `perms` will probably need a modicum amount of special logic.

Comment: using sscanf is faster than `strtok` and `atoi`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think for a perl or shell script it's perfectly fine to read and parse the /proc/ data. In a C program, if robustness is required, I would use a kernel (probably a `sysctl`) interface.

Turns out that the [procps-bundled pmap implementation](http://csourcesearch.net/c/fid018D3CB433BD1C8A2CBAE1F5C57CC0F442F3F686.aspx#L134) parses `/proc/PID/maps` files line-by-line as follows (see `one_proc()` function):

```
sscanf(mapbuf,"%"KLF"x-%"KLF"x %31s %Lx %x:%x %Lu", &start, &end, flags, &file_offset, &dev_major, &dev_minor, &inode);
```

**EDIT**: Original version of my answer showed a way to parse data on shared memory segments only, not **all** mapped memory segments as the OP desired.

I believe `ipcs -m` will give you the same data for multiple processes. So the answer to your second question is that you should read the `ipcs` code: (e.g [BSD version](ftp://ftp.irisa.fr/pub/OpenBSD/src/usr.bin/ipcs/ipcs.c), [Linux version](http://www.koders.com/c/fidCA6258550BB545E3BD35E0D42C81503F439E049B.aspx)):

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just took a look at `ipcs` and it looks like it doesn't quite do what I want, but I'll still take a look to see if its source code can lead me in the right direction.

Comment: @Mike I found the source for the linux version of the util as well. I think the source excerpt I pasted into the answer should give you enough info on how to query and parse the data that you need.

Comment: For such non-trivial pieces of code, I think you should include the code's license statements with them in those snippets you posted.

Comment: @George, thanks. I'll have to experiment with `shmget()`, etc. I can't be sure from looking at this if this is **ALL** memory segments a process owns (which is what I want) or just the ones reserved for shared-memory IPC.

Comment: @Mike I think you're right; you'll only get share memory segments. What you may actually need is source for `pmap` -- but then it's possible that it's simply parsing the /proc/PID/maps file. But in the worst case, you'll learn how to parse it more or less reliably. Good luck!

Comment: +1 for pointing me to `pmap`. I checked, and it's just parsing data in `/proc`. Thanks!

Comment: @Mike Yep, I looked it up as well and edited my answer accordingly. You're welcome, hope this helped.

Comment: What does the KLF suffix stand for? I'm unable to find anything about it. I would have changed %x to %Lx for 64-bit compatibility, but that's probably what that suffix is for?

Comment: @typ1232: See https://github.com/thlorenz/procps/blob/b713185dc7b4c82d8cbc9f4be7e345f09df365bb/deps/procps/proc/procps.h#L34 for definition of KLF

Answer (score 2):

Reading sequentially textual pseudo-files like `/proc/self/maps` is the canonical way, on Linux, to get that information (and there is no easy way to get it otherwise; it is the way the kernel is giving it.).

You could use some library (like `libproc`) which does that for you. But in the end your application will parse (perhaps thru some libraries) files under `/proc`. I'm not sure you are right to avoid that.

Just try to run a command like `ps` or `top` with `/proc` being unmounted. It probably won't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

[`libproc`](http://procps.sourceforge.net/) provides a convenient way to access the content under `/proc`.